# Why isn't my dropdown menu aligned with the dropdown navbar?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

The dropdown menu is working, it is just not aligned with the dropdown navbar.

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">PRODUCTS <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: orange">
    <li><a href="CustomerProducts.aspx">Dumbbells</a></li>
    <li><a href="Apparels.aspx">Apparels</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: you need to show your css codes too before we can help you

Comment: You probably need jsfiddle or something similar to show more of the code before people can help.